# React native reanimated v2 Scale + Opacity withRepeat

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-animated, react-native-reanimated, react-native-reanimated-v2

I am trying to implement scaling View with Opacity togather through **React native reanimated v2**, but not able to contol withRepeat ...

Below code is just Perform scaling withRepeat but not Opacity. How to control Opacity + Scaling of view withRepeat ... Want to apply scaling and Opacity both on view in loop/Repeat.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native';
import Animated,
{ withRepeat, useSharedValue, interpolate, useAnimatedStyle, useDerivedValue, withTiming }
  from 'react-native-reanimated'

import Styles from './Styles';

function LoopApp() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);

  const scaleAnimation = useSharedValue(1);
  const animationOpacityView = useSharedValue(1);

  scaleAnimation.value = withRepeat(withTiming(2.5, { duration: 2000 }), -1, true);
  //animationOpacityView.value = withRepeat(0, -1, true);

  const debug = useDerivedValue(() => {
   // console.log(scaleAnimation.value);
    return scaleAnimation.value;
  });

  const growingViewStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
      transform: [{ scale: scaleAnimation.value }],
      opacity: withTiming(animationOpacityView.value, {
        duration: 1500
      }, () => {
        animationOpacityView.value = 0.99
      })
    };
  });

  return (
    <View style={Styles.container}>
      <Animated.View style={[Styles.viewStyle, growingViewStyle]} />
    </View>
  );
}

export default LoopApp;
```

**Style.js**

```
import {DevSettings, Dimensions, I18nManager} from 'react-native';
import Constants from '../../common/Constants';

const Screen = {
  width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
  height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
};

export default {
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  viewStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#19a35c',
    width: Screen.width * 0.0364,
    height: Screen.width * 0.0364,
    borderRadius: 100,
  },
};
```